# Looping throughTextBoxes in a Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, textbox, panel

I have a panel that contains 5 textboxes, I am trying to loop through the Panel and insert the value of the textbox into the database if it is not 0.

my panel name is Panel1
I honestly do not know from where to start or how to loop in a Panel that contains textfields, any suggestions are appreciated:

Here is my try which it does not compile (I am not sure how to write a loop that loops through a panel)

```
const string query = "INSERT INTO deductible (number) VALUES (@yes)";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
foreach (Panel1 c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.ToString() != "0")
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yes", c.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I also attached a screenshot of my Panel1.
Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to iterate each control within your `Panel` that is a `TextBox`.

```
foreach (TextBox tb in Panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if (tb.Text != "0")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you're gonna get fancy why not `Panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(textbox => textbox.Text != "0")`. :p

Comment: :) Yep, could definitely do that. I was just trying to closely mimic OP's original attempt.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls) { 
    if (control is TextBox) {
        // The code here ...
    }
}
```

The problem though is that you then need to make sure that the order the textboxes are looped over is correct, which adds more maintenance work that is entirely unnecessary. A better approach would be to learn about data binding. Or even more simply, just name your textboxes and assign them directly. Either of those is preferable to using a loop I think.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to loop through items of type `Panel1` in `this.Controls`. What you want to do is loop through items of type `TextBox` in `Panel1.Controls`.

```
foreach(Control c in Panel1.Controls) {
    var textbox = Control As TextBox;
    if(textbox != null){
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

You also want to look at the `Text` property of the TextBox, not call `ToString` on it.

```
if(textbox.Text != "0"){ //do stuff... }
```

And you add a `@yes` parameter to the same command multiple times within the loop, without clearing out the parameters list. I'm not certain if that will work, but if it causes a problem, you should just be able to call `command.Parameters.Clear` to clear the old parameter before adding the new one.